# wp_query for show the post must view and with shortcode

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function

I have try to use this function for show the post most view. But something it's wrong.

I use this also for other things, like show the post by category and in this case work well.

So maybe I have wrong something in the array of `new WP_query`

```
function must_post_read()
{
    global $post;
    $html = "";

    $my_query_2 = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    ));

    if ($my_query_2->have_posts()) : 
        while ($my_query_2->have_posts()) : $my_query_2->the_post();

            $html .= "<p class=\"title\">" . get_the_title() . " </p>";
            $html .= "<p>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
            $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"readmore\">Read more</a>";

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('must_post', 'must_post_read');
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Maybe `post_views_count` saved in DB with prefix like that `_post_views_count`

Comment: Are you sure you have `post_views_count` meta_key for post and why you have used `global $post;`? I think it is not needed over here.

Comment: @RaunakGupta maybe could be, I don't have `post_views_count mat_key`, but is not a wordpress setting? for `global` yes is influent.

Comment: No there is no wordpress setting but if you want you can refer my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42446350/5019802), which can come hand to implement this, but if you still face any problem then tell I'll post an answer over here also.

Comment: thank you @RaunakGupta, understand better now. I have try to use it in different way, but all wrung! sorry I can ask you help to understand who write this code!

Comment: ok, give me 2-3 hr travelling now, will post an answer soon.

Comment: Thank you so much! btw I have try also to use `whpp_track_post_views` and other `meta_key` instead `post_views_count`, but not work... it's correct no? anyway i will wait your answers. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to make sure post has a custom `post_meta` fields on which you 'll be doing your shorting.

```
function whpp_track_post_views($post_id) {
    if (!is_single())
        return;
    if (empty($post_id)) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;
    }
    whpp_set_post_views($post_id);
}

add_action('wp_head', 'whpp_track_post_views');

function whpp_set_post_views($post_id) {
    $count_key = 'whpp_track_post_views';
    $count = get_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, TRUE);
    if ($count == '') {
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, '0');
    } else {
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($post_id, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

//To keep the count accurate, lets get rid of prefetching
remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);

//Short code function
function wh_must_post_read() {
    $html = '';

    $args = [
        'meta_key' => 'whpp_track_post_views', //<--  Check This
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 5
    ];
    
    $my_query_2 = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($my_query_2->have_posts()) :
        while ($my_query_2->have_posts()) : $my_query_2->the_post();

            $html .= "<p class=\"title\">" . get_the_title() . " </p>";
            $html .= "<p>" . get_the_excerpt() . "</p>";
            $html .= "<a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\" class=\"readmore\">Read more</a>";

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('wh_must_post', 'wh_must_post_read');
```

**USAGE**
In PHP

```
echo do_shortcode('[wh_must_post]');
```

In WP Editor

```
[wh_must_post]
```

Please Note: *To see this code in action visit few post single page so that `whpp_set_post_views()` mehord will add `whpp_track_post_views` meta_key to that post.*

*All the above code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Related Question : [How to change the order of posts by number of views not by date in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42446350/5019802)

Comment: Wow! this work very well!! thank you so much! Now I realized which was my mistake! I really owe you a favor!!